# File size limit for upload in Adobe Air

Tags: apache-flex, ftp, air

I am building an Adobe AIR app and integrated an FTP client for file transfers. But I found out that maximum file upload size is 100 MB. I need to transfer bigger files. Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: The maximum file upload size where? On the FTP server? The FTP client? AIR? Which FTP client are you using?

Comment: I am talking about FTP server. I am uploading file from the AIR app to this FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using AIR, then use AIR 2.0's ability to launch native processes and use a command line client to do the file transfers.

Where did you get an AIR / lex based FTP client?  I know there was an open source project ( http://maliboo.pl/projects/FlexFTP/ ). but I understood that the platform limited your ability to give feedback to the user about how much was uploaded.  This would be a bit of a nightmare when dealing with large files.  Has that problem been addressed?  Or is there a work around?

Comment: No there hasnt been much progress to this project since. We were actually looking at using sockets and also the suggestion you posted.Thanx for the response